# NetLogo : How to do multiple operations on lists (find, get , replace, remove , search elements within lists , ....)

Tags: netlogo

I am new to NetLogo and I was wondering if there is a complete reference to do operations on lists, I have read most of the posts here in addition to Netlogo dictionary but for example  if I need a list of pairs of numbers like

```
[[1 2] [2 2] [2 3] ,,, ]
```

when I search

```
member? 3 thislist
```

Will I have the option to say which element of inner list I am considering for the search ? for instance I will get false if it search first element and true if I search second element.

Can anybody please clarify the use of lists in Netlogo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map`, `filter`, `reduce`, `foreach`, `n-values`, and `sort-by` provide customizable operations on lists, using tasks. See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#tasks.

Here's your example using `map`:

```
observer> show member? 3 map first [[1 2] [2 2] [2 3]]
observer: false
observer> show member? 3 map last [[1 2] [2 2] [2 3]]
observer: true
```

Comment: Thanks, but using map means that I need to change the list, what if I need to find a sublist which has 3 and I want to change first element of [2 3] in the main list? how can I use replace-item in this case?

Answer (score 2):

It appears Seth answered your initial question. To answer your follow up question on changing an item, you can use [replace-item](/questions/tagged/replace-item) See: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#listsgroup

or use [map](/questions/tagged/map). Below is an example replacing the first item with a `-99` if the second item is `3`:

```
let aList [[1 2] [2 2] [2 3] [4 4] [5 3]] 
set aList map [(list ifelse-value (item 1 ? = 3) [-99][item 0 ?] item 1 ?)] aList
```