# Netlogo: Retrieve position of a nested list given an element of the nested list

Tags: list, nested-lists, netlogo

I want to retrieve the position of a nested list given an element of the nested list. Is this possible without traversing through all the nested lists?

For example, given a list of lists, [[1.1 a b][1.2 c d][1.3 e f]] I'd like to get the position 1 given element 1.2 .

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to what was asked in this question: [NetLogo : How to do multiple operations on lists (find, get , replace, remove , search elements within lists , ....)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864188/netlogo-how-to-do-multiple-operations-on-lists-find-get-replace-remove)

In your particular case, you can use a combination of [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) to extract the sublist element you're looking for and [`position`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#position) to get its index:

```
observer> show position 1.2 map first [[1.1 "a" "b"][1.2 "c" "d"][1.3 "e" "f"]]
observer: 1
```